# Suggested procedure for making a proposal to the DAO

Tags: the-dao

Is there a guide or reference example about how to make a proposal to the DAO for funding? Besides slock.it are there any more good examples that I should be studying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an overview from an article that came out 10 hours ago on [How to submit a Proposal to the DAO](https://blog.daohub.org/how-to-submit-a-proposal-to-the-dao-59d8bd82cffd#.njr1gdsft):

- Step 1. Write your smart contract, with a link to a [Sample Smart Contract](https://github.com/slockit/DAO/blob/master/SampleOffer.sol)
- Step 2: Post on DAOhub.org
- Step 3: The Community Weighs in
- Step 4: The Curators receive a report

**EDIT 30/05/2016**

See also [How to create a proposal](https://github.com/slockit/DAO/wiki/How-to-create-a-proposal) - from [Where to find the documents matching the dao proposals hash?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4434/where-to-find-the-documents-matching-the-dao-proposals-hash).