# Where to find the documents matching the dao proposals hash?

Tags: the-dao, hash, voting

In each proposals of the DAO there is a hash that I guess is here for us to check the proposal document matches the submission. But where to find these documents? Any official link where links to each proposal are listed? How can we vote if we can't read the original paper? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not that the meaning.

Proposal hash is actually formed by recipent, amount and transaction data:

```
proposalHash = sha3(_recipient, _amount, _transactionData);
```

where

- **recipient**: The recipient of the transaction. This is an address, which can only be the address of the DAO itself, the Curator or an
  address on the whitelist allowedRecipients. Any other address will
  throw an exception, blocking you from creating a new proposal. The
  whitelist is curated by the Curator, and only they can add/remove
  addresses to/from that list. There is an exception to this rule. When
  making a proposal for a new Curator, the recipient is the address of
  the proposed Curator (typically a multisignature account of trusted
  people, or in the case a user is splitting to form their own personal
  DAO, their own account address).

  **amount**: The amount of wei (1 = 10^-18 ether) to be sent from the DAO
  to the recipient in the proposed transaction.

  **transactionData**: The data of the proposed transaction. This is used
  to call functions in the case the recipient is a smart contract, and
  optionally to provide the function parameters of this smart contract
  to the DAO itself.

See more about how to create proposal at the official [GitHub Wiki Page](https://github.com/slockit/DAO/wiki/How-to-create-a-proposal)

Comment: Ok, so where can I find for instance what is the 14th proposal ?

Comment: You can use different sites. The main sites I currently know are http://vote.daohub.org, https://forum.daohub.org, https://dao.consider.it. Remember that the DAO is a Decentralized Autonomous Organization, so everyone need to find a way to convince the crowd controlling it to spend money on their proposal. You can do it like-a-boss as Slock.it, with competence, documentation, videos and media coverage, and so it is more likely that your proposal will pass the quorum and it will be voted yes. Like Kickstarter, money are out there but you need to find your way to reach them and fund your project

Comment: So the document hash is the field hashOfTheProposalDocument that we can see on Slock.it proposal https://live.ether.camp/account/f8c35f1cf2dc4dbeaeeb2ecb298a80b506a5781d I guess, but not anyone created a contract in their proposal. That should be mandatory as a field of the DAO proposal creation method IMO.